# Wordpress Woocommerce price on list not the same as pricen shown on edit page

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have a problem. I'm using Woocommerce plugin and I never edited any default file and there's something wrong with the prices shown. I upload the product via the official API with no problems. If I load the products via browser, it shows the wrong prices.

[image]
[image]

But if I open the product to edit it, it shows the right price.

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening as I've never bothered touching any default core files. I'd appreciate it so much if anybody could help me solve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try putting the price like: `15655.00`? I think that you can set in the woocommerce settings the comma delimited price rules and such...

Comment: Holy cow! Now I understand everything. Woocommerce stores data in the database the unusual way like instead of having the properties as table fields, it does it by having the properties as rows. This way makes wordpress very flexible for plugins to be integrated. And since the values aren't really 'numbers', the API accepts the comma in the number. In our eyes, it's a legit numerical number, in the computer's eyes, it's not, and it's the reason why the product method get_price_html() cannot parse it right! When I removed the comma everything immediately made sense! Thank you so much Sir!

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help :D

Comment: Really Sir thank you so much! Haha I'm actually pretty decent at PHP and I've been editing Wordpress files and making my own PHP websites from scratch for a while now but darn I'm so dumb not to think about and notice your suggestion! Haha, a very good lesson I learned from you good Sir, haha, thank you so much!

Comment: Don't forget to double check your WooCommerce currency settings (`admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=general`). Though, as @dingo_d said already, you don't want to enter thousands separators in the admin, WooCommerce will format the prices automatically based on your currency settings.@dingo_g you should probably write that as an answer so @chris_techno25 can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the price like: 15655.00?

In Woocommerce Settings you can set the currency options where the separators are already handled:

[image]